# Haxe Storing Generic Constraint Types

Tags: generics, types, constraints, haxe

I have this piece of working code that can create instances of some type.

```
typedef Constructible = {
    public function new(entity:Entity):Void;
}
```

The following function simply makes script objects associated to some `Entity`. All scripts inherit from `BehaviorScript`.
So `T` can be `Walk` where `class Walk extends BehaviorScript {}`.

```
// INSIDE OF A CLASS

@:generic
public static function register<T:(Constructible, BehaviorScript)>(type:Class<T>, entity:Entity):T{

    var script = new T(entity);

    entity.addScript(script);

    return script;
}
```

I would like the store the types of all scripts made by the function in a map where the type is the key.

```
// Walk, Attack, Evade classes extend from BehaviorScript

var e = createEntity();
var scriptA = register(Walk, e);
var scriptB = register(Attack, e);
var scriptC = register(Evade, e);

// ISSUE: what to put as key?
var map = new Map<?type as key?, BehaviorScript>();

map.set(Type.getClass(scriptA), scriptA);
map.set(Type.getClass(scriptB), scriptB);
map.set(Type.getClass(scriptC), scriptC);
```

The end goal would be accessing the scripts via type, think of Unity's `getComponent<T>` (maybe there is a better way)

```
getScript<T:BehaviorScript>(type:Class<T>):Null<T>{
     return map.get(type);
}
```

Is there a solution to storing constrained generic types in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class name as the map key:

i.e. `map.set(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(scriptA)), A);`

and `map` is of type `Map<String, BehaviorScript>`

`function getScript(type:Class<T>) return map.get(Type.getClassName(type));`